# Very slow connection to mariadb server

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, debian, database-connection

I've 3 debian's servers:

- Server A: debian with Apache, PHP...
- Server B (old): debian with MySQL
- Server C (new): debian with mariadb

When server A connects to server B, it's very fast: around 0,002s, but when server A connects to server C, it's slow: between 0,3s and 1,5s!

I am using this code to test:

```
$begin = microtime(true);
$db_c = new PDO('mysql:host='.$dburl.';dbname='.$dbtable.';charset=utf8',$dblogin,$dbpass);
$db_c->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$db_c->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_WARNING);
$end = microtime(true);
$temps = $end - $begin;`
```

When I tried to ping server B or C from serer A, I got the same response.

I tried to modify lot of global variables of mariadb. I used the previous global variables of server B to have the same, or better. But nothing changes.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with your program, rather than with the configuration of the servers and their network?  The latter would be outside the scope of Stack Overflow.

Comment: Additional DB information request from your C) mariadb server, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: On your B) mysql server, what is the response in MySQL Command Prompt to  SELECT @@version; ?

Comment: Most of time it's DNS. Try IP instead of hostname and see the difference

Comment: What is the ping time?  (`tracert` or `traceroute`)